# How to install Microsoft Silverlight

Tags: 16.04, moonlight

I have suggested my mother to use Ubuntu (16.04) because she is likely to get viruses while using Windows. She agreed but gave one condition: "I must be able to watch TV-players online", and these are (both using Silverlight):

1. www.player.pl
2. www.vod.tvp.pl

How to make it run?

Comment: I believe google chrome will play silverlight content

Comment: @ravery No, Chrome has abandoned NPAPI plugins entirely. You may be thinking of Netflix, which now uses HTML5 via Chrome instead of Silverlight.

Comment: @wjandrea -- thx. I wonder if silverlight will work in a wine with firefox or mono

Comment: According to [the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605460/how-to-install-microsoft-silverlight-on-firefox-on-12-04#comment1327498_605462), the solution works on 16.04.

Comment: Mind that wine is susceptible to the same viruses ..

Answer (score 1):

Can't test the site player.pl (no free content on the main page) but free content of vod.tvp.pl renders fine on Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Chromium 58.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pipelight claims to be able to install and run (Windows) Silverlight, but I've never had success with it.  Your mileage may vary.

When it works, Pipelight uses Wine to run Windows browser plugins in support of Linux browsers, wrapping the plugin so the browser can use it.  This is likely to be useless now, however, because Firefox has completely dropped the NPAPI some time ago, and Pipelight (last time I checked) used that interface to provide services from Windows plugins.